# Titanium Module not working (Requires License ?)

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am new to titanium (alloy). I am trying to use a Barcode Scanner module (Redlaser). I am getting the following error while trying to start scanning

```
[ERROR] :  StatusManager: Problem reading license file
[ERROR] :  StatusManager: java.io.FileNotFoundException: RedLaser_License.xml
```

Do all the modules required licenses (XML) to run ?

When I view for the scanner comes up, it does not show anything - just a black screen.

Entire Error:

```
[ERROR] :  StatusManager: Problem reading license file
[ERROR] :  StatusManager: java.io.FileNotFoundException: RedLaser_License.xml
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at RLSDK.c.a(RLSDK_:692)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at RLSDK.c.a(RLSDK_:168)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at com.ebay.redlasersdk.BarcodeScanActivity.onCreate(RLSDK_:256)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at ti.redlaser.ScannerActivity.onCreate(ScannerActivity.java:64)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
[ERROR] :  StatusManager:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. In this case, you need register at [RedLaser Developer Portal](http://redlaser.com/developers/portal/)

For iOS RedLaser_License.xml must be at Resources folder, in the other hand, for Android the license file must be at platform/android/bin/assets directory where platform are at the same level of Resources folder.

For more information: [Documentation RedLaser Module](http://appcelerator.marketplace.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/5222/RedLaser-Documentation.zip)

I hope my answer helps you :)

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro, yes it helps a lot :) 
Now, I understand that JAR file and the .so needs to be imported into my project. Any clue how I should do this ? And where the files should be placed ?

Comment: The ti.redlaser-iphone-1.1.0-android-1.1.0.zip must be choiced at Titanium SDK from Help menu -> Install Mobile Module (browse & install) ;)